# Name of this indoor Plant

Tags: identification, houseplants, watering

I purchased below indoor plant but i forgot the name of theis plant + what is the best watering cycle for it

*Click photo for full size*
[image]
<sup>[Image source](https://imgur.com/xoAN4JE)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link currently points to a Dumb Cane (*[Dieffenbachia maculata](https://hgic.clemson.edu/factsheet/dieffenbachia/)*). Has toxic properties so read up on what exactly, will tolerate shade, and for watering add water, then let dry down before watering again; object is to allow the roots to breathe in between waterings.

Comment: Thanks dear . and today i checked whether to add water or not by touching the soil it was moist so i will add water tomorrow or day after tomorrow

Comment: Update: When i moved to new job i left the plant behind they kept overwatering the motherplant  plant and it died. Good thing i took with me one pup with its root intact and now it doing good

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Chinese evergreen (*Aglaonema*), an [easy](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/chinese-evergreen/chinese-evergreen-plants.htm) houseplant. But I am not sure though.

Comment: Close, but it is a dieffenbachia, not an aglo.  They have cylindrical stems